# $state does not transition to defined state in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, automated-tests, bdd, angularjs-routing

I have service that uses $state. I am trying to unit test the service.
I see that $state.current does not change after call of $state.transitionTo.
I checked $stateProvider, it contains states.

**Routes config:**

```
angular.module('EmsWeb.Routes', ['ui.compat']).config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
var defaultView = {
            name: 'defaultView',
            url: '',
            template: '<div />'
        };

        var view = {
            name: 'mainView',
            url: '/view:nodeId:navParams:reqContext', //added reqContext in order to change state parameters that will trigger new navigation to view
            templateUrl: 'MainView.html',
            controller: 'MainAreaCtrl'
        };
$stateProvider.state(defaultView);
        $stateProvider.state(view);
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

**Service code:**

```
angular.module('EmsWeb.Services').factory('MetadataNavigation', ['$q', '$state', '$stateParams', 'DalService', 'ResponseUtil', function ($q, $state, $stateParams, dalService, responseUtil) {
    return {
         hasChangedBroadcastData: function (nodeId, navParams, appContext) {
            if (!$state.is('mainView'))
                return true;
            if ($stateParams.nodeId !=nodeId)
                return true;
            return false;                   
        }
}]);
```

**My test:**

```
    describe("Unit: MetadataNavigation->", function () {
        var service,stateProvider;  

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('EmsWeb.Routes', function ($stateProvider) {
            stateProvider = $stateProvider;
        }));
        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('EmsWeb.Services')); 

        beforeEach(inject(function ($state, MetadataNavigation) {
            service = MetadataNavigation;
            $state.transitionTo('defaultView', {}, false);
//STATE WAS NOT CHANGED
        }));
    describe("hasChangedBroadcastdata:", function () {
            var navParams1, navParams2, nodeId1, nodeId2, appContext1, appContext2, state;  
            beforeEach(inject(function ( AppModel) {                
                appContext1 = AppModel.context;
            }));


            it('broadcastdata has not changed',inject(function ($state) {

                nodeId1 = 'nodeId1';
                nodeId2 = 'nodeId2';
                navParams1 = [{
                    targetName: 'fundId',
                    value: 'LPL.2q.xxxx',
                    display: 'ACLASS'
                }, {
                    targetName: 'fundId',
                    value: 'LPL.2q.yyyy',
                    display: 'BCLASS'
                }];
                navParams2 = [{
                    targetName: 'fundId',
                    value: 'LPL.2q.xxxx',
                    display: 'ACLASS'
                }, {
                    targetName: 'fundId',
                    value: 'LPL.2q.yyyy',
                    display: 'BCLASS'
                }];

                //quick way to copy w/o copying properties
                appContext2 = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(appContext1));

                $state.transitionTo('mainView', { 'nodeId': nodeId1, 'navParams': navParams1, 'reqContext': appContext1.toRequestContext() }, false);
//STATE WAS NOT CHANGED
                expect(service.hasChangedBroadcastData(nodeId2, navParams2, appContext2)).to.be.false;                              
            }));

        });

    });
```

I looked at debugger and $state.current remains the same i.e. $state.current.name is empty and $state.current.abstract is true
I tried different ways to no avail.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if same goes for UI-Router, but often there is missing a Digest Cycle, so the easy out is trying to call $scope.$digest() or $scope.$apply() (you can do that on $rootScope in your case)...

You might have to mock out the $template factory to avoid server calls that the $http backend will fault on (i believe it is called in UI-Router)...

Comment: I was away on vacation, will try as soon as I clean vacation backlog :-)